# Is it possible to override box-sizing:border-box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, packery

I currently use `box-sizing:border-box` on all elements `*` but I've noticed this is conflicting with the packery.js plugin I'm using on each of the elements and I was wondering if there is a way that I can override or reset back to the default for these items?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it back to the default

```
box-sizing: content-box
```

[W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The default style for `box-sizing` is `content-box`:

```
.something {  box-sizing: content-box }
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: @Mathletics. I guess I need M$ documentation too often ^^'